# Determine if a given code uses functsion from a given package

Tags: r, function, package

Is it possible to easily determine if a set of code has used at least one function from a given package?

Or, is the most elegant way to determine this, require that I search the code for each function in the package sequentially?

Comment: Other than a search, What were you thinking?  `grep` would probably work.  Just search the code and look for either of "library" or "require" to find which package, then when you find the package search for the functions

Comment: Thanks @RichardScriven I am not trying to "find which package". I am developing a package, and have a package listed in the Imports section of the DESCRIPTION file. I want to check that this particular package is necessary in my allFunctions.R file (that at least one of its functions is called in my allFunctions.R file).

Comment: I am doing this because when I run R CMD check, I get an error: Namespace in Imports field not imported from: ‘packageName’
  All declared Imports should be used.

Comment: you could list all the functions from a package and use text matching `funs <- ls(package:stats); code <- 'mean(rnorm(10))'; grepl(paste(funs, collapse = '|'), code)`